# Magento 2 : Add "View All" Link after all sub categories

Tags: magento2, topmenu, submenu, sub-categories

How to display "View All" Link after all sub categories in Magento 2.

I used this [blog](https://www.rohanhapani.com/add-custom-link-in-navigation-menu-in-magento-2/). But, It's display main menu and sub menu. I want to add "View All" in all sub categories after 5 categories.

How to Add "View All" Link?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override block and apply this functionality using this below way :

Create **di.xml** for add preference :

> **app/code/RH/CustomLinkAdd/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="RH\CustomLinkAdd\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

Create Topmenu file on below path and paste below code :

> **app/code/RH/CustomLinkAdd/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace RH\CustomLinkAdd\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node\Collection;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Cache identities
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $identities = [];

    /**
     * Top menu data tree
     *
     * @var Node
     */
    protected $_menu;

    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    private $nodeFactory;

    /**
     * @var TreeFactory
     */
    private $treeFactory;

    private $categoryFactory;

    protected $isLastNode = "";
    protected $indexCounter = 0;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param NodeFactory $nodeFactory
     * @param TreeFactory $treeFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        TreeFactory $treeFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $nodeFactory, $treeFactory, $data);
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    private function getChildLevel($parentLevel): int
    {
        return $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;
    }
    private function removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent(Collection $children, int $childLevel): void
    {
        /** @var Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
                $children->delete($child);
            }
        }
    }
    private function setCurrentClass(Node $child, string $outermostClass): void
    {
        $currentClass = $child->getClass();
        if (empty($currentClass)) {
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        } else {
            $child->setClass($currentClass . ' ' . $outermostClass);
        }
    }
    private function shouldAddNewColumn(array $colBrakes, int $counter): bool
    {
        return count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake'];
    }
    protected function _getRenderedMenuItemAttributes(Node $item)
    {
        $html = '';
        foreach ($this->_getMenuItemAttributes($item) as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
            $html .= ' ' . $attributeName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attributeValue) . '"';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's attributes
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemAttributes(Node $item)
    {
        return ['class' => implode(' ', $this->_getMenuItemClasses($item))];
    }

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's classes
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemClasses(Node $item)
    {
        $classes = [
            'level' . $item->getLevel(),
            $item->getPositionClass(),
        ];

        if ($item->getIsCategory()) {
            $classes[] = 'category-item';
            $this->isLastNode = "";
        }

        if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
            $this->isLastNode = "";
        }

        if ($item->getIsActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        } elseif ($item->getHasActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'has-active';
        }

        if ($item->getIsLast()) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
            $this->isLastNode = "last";
        }

        if ($item->getClass()) {
            $classes[] = $item->getClass();
        }

        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        return $classes;
    }
    protected function _getHtml(
        Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        array $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $childLevel = $this->getChildLevel($menuTree->getLevel());
        $this->removeChildrenWithoutActiveParent($children, $childLevel);

        $counter = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        /** @var Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter === 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter === $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel === 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $this->setCurrentClass($child, $outermostClass);
            }

            if ($this->shouldAddNewColumn($colBrakes, $counter)) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }
            
            $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                $child->getName()
            ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                $child,
                $childLevel,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $limit
            ) . '</li>';
            $counter++;
        }
        if($childLevel > 0)
        {
            $positionArr = explode("-", $child->getPositionClass());
            // Display after 5 subcategory
            if(count($positionArr) > 5)
            {
                if(end($positionArr) > 3 && $this->isLastNode == "last")
                { 
                    $html .='<li class="level'. $childLevel .' view-all">';
                    $html .=         '<a class="level'. $childLevel .'" href="'. $child->getParent()->getUrl() .'">';
                    $html .=             'View All';
                    $html .=         '</a>';
                    $html .=     '</li>';
                }
            }
        }

        if (is_array($colBrakes) && !empty($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    protected function _addSubMenu($child, $childLevel, $childrenWrapClass, $limit)
    {
        $html = '';
        if (!$child->hasChildren()) {
            return $html;
        }

        $colStops = [];
        if ($childLevel == 0 && $limit) {
            $colStops = $this->_columnBrake($child->getChildren(), $limit);
        }
        $html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . ' ' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
        $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colStops);
        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Clean cache and check it.